# GNSSアドオンボードでgetDCReportを呼び出すとNavDataが更新されなくなる

Tags: spresense

SpresenseのGNSSアドンボードを用いてみちびきのDCreportを取得するアプリケーションの実装をしていますが、
spGnssAddonクラス上のgetDCreportメソッドを呼び出し以降getNavDataで取得したデーターが更新されなくなりました。
ブートローダーの更新も試してみましたが改善しません。
spGnssAddonクラスを用いて正常にgetDCreportを実行できる方法をご教授シテいただけませんでしょうか。

以下に検証に用いたコードを添付します。

```
#include <GNSS.h>
#define SELECTSAT (SpSatelliteType)(GPS | QZ_L1CA | QZ_L1S)
//static SpGnss Gnss;
static SpGnssAddon Gnss;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  if (Gnss.begin() != 0) {
    Serial.println("Gnss begin error!!");
  } else if (Gnss.start() != 0) {
    Serial.println("Gnss start error!!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Gnss setup OK");
    Gnss.setInterval(SpInterval_1Hz);
    Gnss.select(SELECTSAT);
  }
}

void loop() {
  static char c = 0;
  if (Gnss.waitUpdate(-1)) {
    if (c++ % 2 == 1) {
      ledOn(LED0);
    } else {
      ledOff(LED0);
    }
    SpNavData NavData;
    Gnss.getNavData(&NavData);

    if (NavData.posDataExist && (NavData.posFixMode != FixInvalid)) {
      ledOn(LED1);
    } else {
      ledOff(LED1);
    }

    if ((NavData.satelliteType & QZ_L1S) != 0) {
      ledOn(LED2);
    } else {
      ledOff(LED2);
    }

    SpGnssTime time = NavData.time;
    Serial.printf("%04d/%02d/%02d ", time.year, time.month, time.day);
    Serial.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d.%06ld\n", time.hour, time.minute, time.sec, time.usec);
    if (NavData.posFixMode == FixInvalid) {
      Serial.print("No-Fix, ");
    } else {
      Serial.print("Fix, ");
    }
    if (NavData.posDataExist == 0) {
      Serial.print("No Position");
    } else {
      Serial.print("Lat=");
      Serial.print(NavData.latitude, 6);
      Serial.print(", Lon=");
      Serial.print(NavData.longitude, 6);
    }
    Serial.println("");

    struct cxd56_gnss_dcreport_data_s *handle = Gnss.getDCReport();
    if (handle) {
      ledOn(LED3);
      Serial.println(handle->svid);
    } else {
      ledOff(LED3);
    }
  }
}
```

上記のコードのspGnssAddonをspGnssに変更してアドオンボードを外した場合は正常に動作しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現行のGNSS Add-onボードでは、災危通報機能には対応しておりません。
今後、GNSS Add-onボードのファームウェアアップデートにより対応を予定しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます